# Is there a difference between partial application and returning a function?

Tags: scala, currying, partial-application

In terms of under the hood: stack/heap allocation, garbage collection, resources and performance, what is the difference between the following three:

```
def Do1(a:String) = { (b:String) => { println(a,b) }}
def Do2(a:String)(b:String) = { println(a,b) }
def Do3(a:String, b:String) = { println(a,b) }

Do1("a")("b")
Do2("a")("b")
(Do3("a", _:String))("b")
```

Except the obvious surface differences in declaration about how much arguments each takes and returns

Comment: Well, this has nothing to do with currying. In any case, the question was about under the hoods.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the an important part of your question: how it relates to memory allocation. I still think there's a lot of relevant info in the related question, but it's not a duplicate, you're right.

Comment: I would guess on a bytecode level that `Do2` and `Do3` are the same. Your call to `Do2` is likely a simple method call, whereas I'd expect the `Do3` call to create an intermediate function object. `Do1` should do that anyway. Maybe someone with more time right now could do a `javap` and write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompiling the following class (note the additional call to `Do2` compared to your question):

```
class Test {
  def Do1(a: String) = { (b: String) => { println(a, b) } }
  def Do2(a: String)(b: String) = { println(a, b) }
  def Do3(a: String, b: String) = { println(a, b) }

  Do1("a")("b")
  Do2("a")("b")
  (Do2("a") _)("b")
  (Do3("a", _: String))("b")
}
```

yields this pure Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public Function1<String, BoxedUnit> Do1(final String a) {
        new AbstractFunction1() {
            public final void apply(String b) {
                Predef..MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
            }
        };
    }

    public void Do2(String a, String b) {
        Predef..MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
    }

    public void Do3(String a, String b) {
        Predef..MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
    }

    public Test() {
        Do1("a").apply("b");
        Do2("a", "b");
        new AbstractFunction1() {
            public final void apply(String b) {
                Test.this.Do2("a", b);
            }
        }.apply("b");
        new AbstractFunction1() {
            public final void apply(String x$1) {
                Test.this.Do3("a", x$1);
            }
        }.apply("b");
    }
}
```

(this code doesn't compile, but it suffices for analysis)

---

Let's look at it part by part (Scala & Java in each listing):

```
def Do1(a: String) = { (b: String) => { println(a, b) } }

public Function1<String, BoxedUnit> Do1(final String a) {
    new AbstractFunction1() {
        public final void apply(String b) {
            Predef.MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
        }
    };
}
```

No matter how `Do1` is called, a new Function object is created.

---

```
def Do2(a: String)(b: String) = { println(a, b) }

public void Do2(String a, String b) {
    Predef.MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
}

def Do3(a: String, b: String) = { println(a, b) }

public void Do3(String a, String b) {
    Predef.MODULE$.println(new Tuple2(a, b));
}
```

`Do2` and `Do3` compile down to the same bytecode. The difference is exclusively in the `@ScalaSignature` annotation.

---

```
Do1("a")("b")

Do1("a").apply("b");
```

`Do1` is straight-forward: the returned function is immediately applied.

```
Do2("a")("b")

Do2("a", "b");
```

With `Do2`, the compiler sees that this is not a partial application, and compiles it to a single method invocation.

---

```
(Do2("a") _)("b")

new AbstractFunction1() {
    public final void apply(String b) {
        Test.this.Do2("a", b);
    }
}.apply("b");

(Do3("a", _: String))("b")

new AbstractFunction1() {
    public final void apply(String x$1) {
        Test.this.Do3("a", x$1);
    }
}.apply("b");
```

Here, `Do2` and `Do3` are first partially applied, then the returned functions are immediately applied.

---

**Conclusion:**

I would say that `Do2` and `Do3` are mostly equivalent in the generated bytecode. A full application results in a simple, cheap method call. Partial application generates anonymous Function classes at the caller. What variant you use depends mostly on what intent you're trying to communicate.

`Do1` always creates an immediate function object, but does so in the called code. If you expect to do partial applications of the function a lot, the using this variant will reduce your code size, and maybe trigger the JIT-Compiler earlier, because the same code is called more often. Full application will be slower, at least before the JIT-Compiler inlines and subsequently eliminates object creations at individual call sites. I'm not an expert on this, so I don't know whether you can expect that kind of optimization. My best guess would be that you can, for pure functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed analysis and especially the conclusion. Appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome! Sorry again for missing the point of your question at first. Answering it was very interesting!